# Does a storage HDD need a page file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, virtual-memory, pagefile

I've an HDD used only for storing files (i.e., not used for installing software). Do I need to set a page file for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: You give pagefiles to an OS, not to a specific disk. What you are thinking of, is Windows allows you to have multiple pagefiles, on more drive across many disks, in case of low disk space on any one drive. Given the rapid increase in drive space in recent years, you will not run in this situation. Generally, its best to put your pagefile on the fastest disk you have, so that pageswaps are done quickly.

There is some debate on the merits of putting your pagefile (or swapfile for other os) on a SSD vs the writelife of the SSD, but that is a whole different debate.

Comment: To clarify, I have 3 HDDs, C, D, E, so if I set the page file to drive E, it's actually for the OS and not for drive E?

Comment: Yes, you just happen to be storing it on E. Windows knows where its at, and doesnt care which drive(s) its on.

Comment: I do generally put very IO intensive swap files on a second OS. For example Photoshop will generally have its own swap / scratch disk.

Comment: @AthomSfere: Don't you mean "second drive"?

Comment: Ah, geez. Yes. A Second drive / disk  for scratch. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Usually not. I've been running my Win7 for years now with 0mb paging file. Just make sure to have a large-enough RAM availability.